# Automatically open a remote desktop connection upon login

Tags: x11, linux-mint, session, remote-desktop

I have installed Linux Mint to one of my desktop PCs. I have downloaded and installed Freerdp-x11 for me to connect into my Windows Terminal Server. I want the terminal command line to connect automatically to the Windows terminal server, so that every time I boot my Linux Mint PC, I wouldn't have to keep typing `xfreerdp 000.000.0.000` on the terminal command line. Is there a script for it?

Comment: How can i set autologin to this so that it will automatically login into rdp session when i boot. Also i would like to now if theres a way to set it without any other programs or graphical enviroment on the background. Only rdp and autologin? is there a script for that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Linux Mint tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/988):

To run a command after you log in, select "Preferences > Startup Applications" in the system menu. Click "Add", enter a name, and enter `xfreerdp 000.000.0.000` as the command. This is analogous to adding a shortcut in the "Startup" menu under Windows.

(Note that this is somewhat dependent on the desktop environment and on how the distribution sets it up. Most desktop environments have something similar, but it may be located in a different menu and have a different name.)